# Why my 4 bit binary half adder circuit design is showing incompatible width in LOGISIM?

Tags: logic

I am trying to create a half adder circuit using logisim to compute two 4 bit binary numbers but somehow Logisim tells me that I have incompatible widths and I therefore have to change the bit width of every single component including the carry-out which is suppose to be a 1 bit (showing carry 1 or carry 0). Now I understand that my output has to be at least 4 bit in length and I need an extra bit as a carry out but even when I change the length the way Logisim wants then my design does not work anymore.

[Half adder of a 2 four bit binaries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVa0T.png)

Answer (score 1):

It's simply because the input width on the AND gate is 1 bit. You can't  have a 4-bit output going into a 1-bit input.